# status of AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there another way to find out the status of services on AppEngine other than the link given in the error below?

LogAndContinueErrorHandler handleServiceError: Service error in memcache
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache getIdentifiables: exception getting multiple keys
...
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CapabilityDisabledException: The API call memcache.Set() is temporarily unavailable: Memcache is temporarily unavailable. Please see http://code.google.com/status/appengine for more information.

I check it but it shows an error rate of 0% for all categories.

Comment: Currently I've the same issue with my memcache :(  The GAE status dashboard is all green.  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific memcache issue now appears to be resolved, but in general you should use the Capabilities API ([Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/capabilities/) and [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/capabilities/)) to check if an API is currently unavailable.